# jQuery scrollTop - Issue with wrong hash

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do scrollTop animation to an anchor that resides inside of a fullscreen `<section>`, but **does not scroll to right anchor at first click**. Here's my code.

```
<nav id="scroller"> <a href="#subBox1">Scroll me to sub 1</a>
 <a href="#subBox2">Scroll me to sub 2</a>
 <a href="#subBox3">Scroll me to sub 3</a>

</nav>
<section id="boxTop"></section>
<section id="boxMaster">
    <section id="subBox1">
        <p>Hello. I am the Sub 1!</p>
    </section>
    <section id="subBox2">
        <p>Hello. I am the Sub 2!</p>
    </section>
    <section id="subBox3">
        <p>Hello. I am the Sub 3!</p>
    </section>
</section>
```

---

```
$("#scroller a").click(function () {
    $('#boxMaster').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
    }, 700);
    $("#scroller a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

**[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/58rjowuL/)**

```js
$("#scroller a").click(function() {
  $('#boxMaster').animate({
    scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
  }, 700);
  $("#scroller a").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#scroller {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
#scroller a {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#scroller a.active {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
#boxTop {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}
#boxMaster {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#boxMaster #subBox1,
#boxMaster #subBox2,
#boxMaster #subBox3 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
}
p {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="scroller"> <a href="#subBox1">Scroll me to sub 1</a>
  <a href="#subBox2">Scroll me to sub 2</a>
  <a href="#subBox3">Scroll me to sub 3</a>

</nav>
<section id="boxTop"></section>
<section id="boxMaster">
  <section id="subBox1">
    <p>Hello. I am the Sub 1!</p>
  </section>
  <section id="subBox2">
    <p>Hello. I am the Sub 2!</p>
  </section>
  <section id="subBox3">
    <p>Hello. I am the Sub 3!</p>
  </section>
</section>
```

Comment: What the exact problem?

Comment: Hm, did you saw fiddle example? Does not navigate to the right anchor at first click @phts

Comment: Something strange happening - sometimes it doesn't scroll at all. For example on load: click on 1st -> click on 2nd -> click on 3rd - 3rd click doesn't scroll to the 3rd slide

Comment: Neither on a second click. Please, next time at least, ask a question or comment your codelet @fiskolin

Comment: Sorry, my bad @PhilSummers Question edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to scroll the `#boxMaster` element *relative* to the link's position within the element *and* relative to the `#boxMaster` element's `top` position within the `body` element.

You can do this by adding the `#boxMaster` element's `scrollTop()` value with its `top` position, and then subtracting that from the link's offset `top` value:

```
$(this.hash).offset().top - $('#boxMaster').position().top + $('#boxMaster').scrollTop()
```

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/tk6ta2ey/)

```
var $boxMaster = $('#boxMaster');
$boxMaster.animate({
    scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top - $boxMaster.position().top + $boxMaster.scrollTop()
}, 700);
```

You may also need to prevent the link element's default behavior using `e.preventDefault()`, and then manually scroll the `html`/`body` element to the `#boxMaster` element:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/tk6ta2ey/)

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $boxMaster.offset().top
}, 700);
```

Comment: Note that multiple jqueries (such as several $('#boxMaster') in exemple 2) are suboptimal. Asking once for the DOM element and storing it in a variable is a better practice.

Comment: @PhilSummers Yeah, I know, it's not like your answer cached the variable either. Anyways, I went ahead and updated the example and code snippets.

Answer (score 3):

Add the current scroller value to the `offset().top()`, the latter beeing relative to the top of frame, and get rid of `this.hash`. Use `this.href` instead.

```
$("#scroller a").click(function () {
    var y=$('#boxMaster').scrollTop()
    $('#boxMaster').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this.href).offset().top + y
    }, 100);
});
```

Comment: I did a similar experience at first time, but only `#sub3` worked well at first click, as your example.

Comment: Generally works but still doesn't open 1st slide on 1st link *initial* click

Comment: It did not before I edited to mention that this.hash is the other problem. Try with  this.hash.offset().top + y  instead

Answer (score 0):

I have a fixed header. I started with [w3school's code](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_animate_smoothscroll). However, I've been struggling with this same problem for so long, finally found a workaround for the "first click incorrect" issue:

Just before (outside) of my click event, I simply created a variable "x", initialized:

```
var x=1;
```

Then I have a conditional statement inside the click event checking for x:

```
    if (x==1) {
        console.log("x is now: " + x);
        x=0;
        console.log("x is now: " + x);
        jQuery("html, body").animate({ 
            scrollTop: jQuery("div.class-of-element-i-am-scrolling-to" + hash).position().top - jQuery("div.header-container").outerHeight(true) - jQuery("h3.another-element-in-my-way").outerHeight(true)
            }, 2000, function(){
            return false;
        });
    } else {
        jQuery("html, body").animate({ 
            scrollTop: jQuery("div.class-of-element-i-am-scrolling-to" + hash).position().top
            }, 2000, function(){
            return false;
        });
    }
```

In other words, using "x" as a flag to check if it is the first time the code is run.

If it is, then I am kind of cheating by subtracting the fixed header and the other elements that are pulling my desired div up.  Remember to make "x=0" to "drop" the flag.

If it isn't, then it works fine anyway.